# OneDrive for business API 2.0 Download File content return Unauthorized 401

Tags: onedrive

I created an Azure AD application that has full access (R&W) to the OneDrive API using application permissions. (my application is a daemon app.)
These permissions are granted & approved.

HTTP GET 
https://{MyTenant}.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/drives//root://Document.docx
-> Returns 200 and content contains JSON information about the file

GET 
2016-12-24T14:15:31.458 Requested uri: https://{MyTenant}.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/drives//root://Document.docx:/content

2016-12-24T14:15:31.888 StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  X-SharePointHealthScore: 0
  SPRequestGuid: c935c49d-a0fa-3000-a357-32b18090ecd4
  request-id: c935c49d-a0fa-3000-a357-32b18090ecd4
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
  X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
  SPRequestDuration: 140
  SPIisLatency: 1
  MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 16.0.0.6008
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
  Cache-Control: private
  Date: Sat, 24 Dec 2016 14:15:31 GMT
  P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
  WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
  X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Length: 16
  Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
}
2016-12-24T14:15:31.888 401 UNAUTHORIZED

I added the Authorization header correctly.  I created an Upload Function that sends the file to the same Document library and that works also correctly, same with the Delete functionality.

What is the reason of this 401, only when requesting the /content of the file?
How could I troubleshoot this?  Can anyone help me out here?

I am running out of ideas here :o

Best regards,
Jens

Comment: Anyone any ideas here?

Comment: I am really blocked here. I loaded the JWT token into jwt.io :

It has the following Roles :

  "roles": [
    "TermStore.ReadWrite.All",
    "Sites.Manage.All",
    "TermStore.Read.All",
    "Sites.Read.All",
    "Sites.ReadWrite.All",
    "Sites.FullControl.All"
  ],

What is going on here?

The requested URI is : 
https://<myTenantName>.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/drives/<myDriveName>/root:/faas.pptx:/content

Comment: Just tested : when using both types of GET request
GET /drive/items/{item-id}/content
GET /drive/root:/{path and filename}:/content

-> return 401 Unauthorized.

Comment: @RyanGregg : Any ideas here to solve this?

Comment: Hey Jens, There is a known issue with using app-only tokens to download files and we are actively working to fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks. I currently fixed it by using the SharePoint API for downloading files.

Comment: FYI. The fix to download file content using app-only tokens is now deployed.